# Should I check the authorization of a user inside every view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

So I'm working on a MVC project in .NET Core 2.1.
I use the built in Cookie authentication from ASP.NET Identity.

All my endpoints inside my controller that would require authorization are annotated with `[Authorize]` of course. But, do my views (that get returned) also need a form of annotation to define they are only accessible for users that are authorized? If that is the case how would you do that?

Comment: Only if you (perhaps) share the view between Authorized and Non-authorized actions. Otherwise, there's no way to reach them unless you're authorized and they therefore the auth status of the user doesn't require any further validation.

Comment: And even though. There shouldn't be any logic in there. Only reuse of the data prepared by the controller.

Comment: Ok, but for example: 
After I call LogOutAsync() from my logout endpoint, I'm still able to use the return button from my browser to access that view again. Or is that issue not related to my question?

Comment: you mean the browser "Back" button? Probably your browser cached the page. If you hit F5 to reload your page then - if your application is working correctly - it is likely to prompt you to log back in. (P.S. The view itself is only some HTML which is generated when the server executes a controller action method - which you've mentioned have all got appropriate authorisation code implemented. There's no other way to get the application to produce that HTML, so the notion of views having separate authorisation from the controller methods doesn't really make any sense.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the authentication or autorization in a .cshtml-View contradicts the MVC-concept in my opinion. When the request hits the "View"-part of MVC there was already a corresponding controller involved which did its job and called the view engine. At this Point you are (or should be) done with handling business logic - and permissions are just another form of business requirement - and present its result the most fabulous way.

So to answer your question concretely:

> But, do my views (that get returned) also need a form of annotation to define they are only accessible for users that are authorized?

Since they are only accessible through controllers (or should be), they don't need additional annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Views or partial views can only be accessed by any action of controller so if you apply `[Authorize]` filter on controller or action then no need to use that in view.

But if want to authenticate the user in view then You can use Identity User's extention method `IsInRole("Role")`.